# Networkmanager log: unsuccessful login

Tags: network-manager

How can I find out the name of the network where my ubuntu 18.04 failed to login in for a specific date?
With

```
journalctl --since "2021-02-18 09:00:00" --until "2021-02-18 12:00:00" /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
```

I get no results, but I know that in this period I tried to connect via WiFi to a network unsuccessfully.
(Alternatively I tried to figure this out by history of Firefox since when trying to connect there opend a website from the network. But this website has not been registered as "visited" as far as I see).

Answer (score 0):

First, some Logging advice:

```
# do this once (or forever have to `sudo journalctl`)
sudo adduser $USER systemd-journal 
# then either logout/login or `newgrp systemd-journal`

# add to ~/.bash_aliases or ~/.bashrc 
# tsjou "18-11-01 01:55:28" for journalctl --since 
alias tsjou="date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'" 
# use other `date` options, e.g. `tsjou --date=yesterday`
# make "journalctl" easier to type
alias jc=journalctl 

# record beginning for journalctl (a thumbtack in the log flow)
alias jstart="my_JSTART_TIME=\"\$(tsjou)\"" 
# show all logs since `jstart`
alias jend="journalctl --since=\"\$my_JSTART_TIME\""

# what happened in the last 5 or 10 minutes?
alias jc5="journalctl --since=\"-5 minutes\"" 
alias jc10="journalctl --since=\"-10 minutes\"" 
# what has NetworkManager logged since boot?
alias jcnet="journalctl -b 0 _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service"
```

Then, once you have read access to the logs, your `journalctl --since=...` should work.

Read `man journalctl date`.

Comment: Having done what you suggested I now assume that the problem is that network connections are not logged, i . e. executing `journalctl --since=...` does not show connections to network; neither successful attempts nor unsuccessful.